# SQL Where Statement <>

Tags: sql, string, select, automation, where-clause

All - I am creating a larger RPA project.

I need to write a simple SQL Where statement but cannot get it working.

```
    SELECT * FROM [$vWorksheet$$] WHERE CSV_Extracted<>"Extracted";
```

I wish to only extract data if the data within column header "CSV_Extracted" is not equal to "extracted".

i have validated that the

```
  SELECT * FROM [$vWorksheet$$] is working as expected
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starter: use single quotes for string literals. In many databases, double quotes stand for identifiers, which would cause your query to error:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CSV_Extracted <> 'Extracted';
```

Then, if the column is `null`able, and you want to allow `null` values, then you need additional logic to handle that. In standard SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CSV_Extracted IS DISTINCT FROM 'Extracted';
```

A more portable syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CSV_Extracted IS NULL OR CSV_Extracted <> 'Extracted';
```